# CKAN installation with docker-compose

Tags: ckan

I am very new to ckan and I am currently trying to install one using docker compose. I was just wondering if I needed to set up a virtual env first and install ckan there or not. Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to run CKAN locally using `docker-compose.yml`, have a look at the documentation provided by the more popular `docker-ckan` repos, I quite like the [Open Knowledge](https://github.com/okfn/docker-ckan) one. They provide all the necessary files to run and the default environment variables that will successfully run your CKAN instance locally